# How to refer to a Cell in a ASP.NET GridView without using its index?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, .net-2.0

I was wondering if there is a way to identify and to refer to a Cell by Name or Id in a Asp.Net GridView.

In my case, I have this situation, where I want to access a ImageButton control inside a TemplateField.

My code is like this :

```
 ImageButton ibtStatus = (ImageButton)e.Row.Cells[8].FindControl(ibtIDStatus);
```

But I'd like to refer to the cell like this :

```
 ImageButton ibtStatus = (ImageButton)e.Row.Cells["MyCell"].FindControl(ibtIDStatus);
```

How to refer to the Cell by a name, HeaderText or any other way that is not by its index?

Edited : I am using Visual Studio 2005, and .NET 2.0.

Comment: Why do you want to find the control inside a specific cell? You could get the same result by searching the Row element (e.Row.FindControl("yourControlID")).

Comment: Hum... I think I was not happy with my example. I also would like to hide some specific Cell, like `e.Row.Cells[4].Visible = false` How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to bypass the cell index altogether and do this without any problem.

```
ImageButton ibtStatus = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl(ibtIDStatus);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are writing this code in GridView_RowDataBound Event.... Right  ?? ?

The better approach to write the code is.

```
ImageButton ibtStatus  = e.Row.FindControl("ibtIDStatus") as ImageButton;
if(ibtStatus !=null)
{
// Write your code here.
}
```

I Hope this will help you out.